# Spring MVC Abstract Controller::How to get exact method signature when implementing an abstract controller interface

Tags: eclipse, spring

I am using STS 2.8.1 and Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.

I have an Abstract controller like below

```
public abstract class SuperController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/Entity", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/xml,application/json")
    public abstract @ResponseBody OAuthEntity setOAuthEntity(@RequestBody OAuthEntity oAuthEntity);

@RequestMapping(value = "/Entity/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/xml,application/json")
    public abstract @ResponseBody OAuthEntity getOAuthEntity(@PathVariable("id") Long id);
}
```

When I extend the controller in STS it gives me method signature like below

```
    @Override
public OAuthEntity setOAuthEntity(OAuthEntity oAuthEntity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public OAuthEntity getOAuthEntity(Long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

I understand that the @RequestMapping are inherited fine and I have also tested the code (it works!!). 
What I want is that when I extend the super class I should get the @ResponseBody, @PathVariable("id") and @RequestBody as in abstract class.

Of course I could edit it manually (that's what I am doing, but would like a more elegant way) So that the Sub class has method signature like below

```
    @Override
public @ResponseBody OAuthEntity setOAuthEntity(@RequestBody OAuthEntity oAuthEntity) {

    @Override
public @ResponseBody OAuthEntity getOAuthEntity(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
```

It is not killing me but frustrating to have to manually write it.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Spring 3 did away with the notion of interitance for Controllers.  My advice would be to ditch the abstract Controller idea and simply add those annotations to controllers.

Inheritance doesn't make any sense in this context.  You want one and only one controller method to be handling a given request mapping in your application.  There's no need for a parent/child relationship, in my opinion.  I'd advise that you move those annotations into appropriate controller implementations and remove your abstract class.

Comment: I wanted to have the same method signatures across multiple controllers hence the parent/child relationship. In that way I can have different implementations for different contexts, e.g. super controller is OauthController and children are /google, /facebook etc..